# Comparison of streaming message implementations in protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

What are the trade-offs, advantages and disadvantages of each of these streaming implementations where multiple messages of the same type are encoded?

Are they any different at all ? What I want achieve is to store a vector of box'es, into a protobuf.

**Impl 1 :**

```
package foo;

message Boxes
{ 
  message Box 
  { required int32 w = 1;
    required int32 h = 2;
  }

  repeated Box boxes = 1; 
}
```

**Impl 2:**

```
package foo;

message Box 
{ required int32 w = 1;
  required int32 h = 2;
}

message Boxes 
{ repeated Box boxes = 1; 
}
```

**Impl 3 :** Stream multiple of these messages into the same file.

```
package foo;

message Box 
{ required int32 w = 1;
  required int32 h = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1 & 2 only change where / how the types are declared. The work itself will be identical.

3 is more interesting: you can't *just* stream `Box` after `Box` after `Box`, because the root object in protobuf is not terminated (to allow concat === merge). If you *only* write `Box`es, when you deserialize you will have exactly one `Box` with the last `w` and `h` that were written. You need to add a length-prefix; you could do that arbitrarily, but: *if* you happen to choose to "varint"-encode the length, you're close to what the `repeated` gives you - except the `repeated` also includes a field-header (field 1, type 2 - so binary 1010 = decimal 10) before each "varint" length.

If I were you, I'd just use the `repeated` for simplicity. Which of 1 / 2 you choose would depend on personal choice.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. What I meant in 3 was streaming by including the length parameter (which I had learned from another of your answer and protobuf documentation). That said, the difference between length added streaming and default "repeated" made my understanding clearer. W.r.t 1 & 2, is there any ramification for these choices ?

Comment: One other point, option's 1 & 2 serialise / deserialise all the box's at once while 3 will serialise / deserialise box by box. If you are talkingabout  millions / billions of box's, option 3 may be preferable (much less memory is needed). Not sure which language you are using , but Java implements a Delimited Message (which support option 3).

Comment: @BruceMartin you should add that in an answer'

Answer (score 11):

Marc Gravell answer is certainly correct, but one point he missed is

- option's 1 & 2 (Repeated option) will serialise / deserialise **all the box's at once**
- option 3 (multiple messages in the file) will serialise / deserialise **box by box**.
  If using java, you can use delimited files (which will add a Var-Int length at the start of the message).

Most of the time it will not matter wether you use a Repeated or Multiple messages, but if there are millions / billions of box's, memory will be an issue for option's 1 and 2 (Repeated) and option 3 (multiple messages in the file) would be the best to choose.

So in summary:

- If there millions / billions of Boxes use - **Option 3 (multiple messages in the file)**.
- Otherwise use one of the **Repeated options (1/2)** because it simpler and supported across all Protocol buffers versions.

Personally  I would like to see  a "standard" Multiple Message format

Comment: It is possible to write a bunch of Boxes-messages (1/2) after each other, without any separator. They will automatically merge and when you read, it will all be a single big repeated field.